# System.NotSupportedException with WebClient on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone, webclient

I am having a bit of an issue in using WebClient on Windows Phone 7. I am currently trying to use it by downloading a file into a string so that I can parse the string using JSON.NET. Unfortunately, I am can't even seem to get the file into a string just yet. Here is my code:

```
private void GetFileAsString()
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(sClient_DownloadStringCompleted);  
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(searchData.searchurl, UriKind.Relative));
}
private void sClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        textBlock1.Text = e.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        textBlock1.Text = e.Error.ToString();
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the error I am receiving: http://k.min.us/jzvIAYJ18uQbV.png

I've looked online quite a bit and can't seem to find a solution to this problem, including in previous posts on this site. Any help here is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does searchurl begin with http:// or https:// ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup [`BaseAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.baseaddress%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property on your `WebClient` instance correctly when you use `UriKind.Relative` , alternatively just use absolute `Uri` - otherwise it tries to use your xap's origin `Uri`...

Answer (score 0):

MSDN documentation suggests two possible issues you could be running into.  You haven't given us enough info to say for sure.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202(v=VS.95).aspx

> This method retrieves the specified resource using the GET method. The
> resource is downloaded asynchronously. When the download is completed,
> the DownloadStringCompleted event is raised. The downloaded string is
> available in the Result property of the
> DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs. You cannot call the
> DownloadStringAsync method again on the same WebClient object, until
> the first string download operation is completed. Doing this causes an
> exception.
>
> If the BaseAddress property is not an empty string and
> the address does not contain an absolute URI, the address must be a
> relative URI that is combined with BaseAddress to form the absolute
> URI of the requested data.